# Client submitted jQuery selectors, is it safe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, xss, jquery-1.8

Is it XSS safe to allow clients to submit jQuery selectors?

I would run a selector string submitted potentially by trolls and put it into `$('')` to select elements on the page.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120938/exploiting-xss-in-jquery-selector might want to read this

Comment: Safe? That's really on the Server, as Client data can always be manipulated.

Comment: @PHPglue not true, XSS can introduce keylogging into your page without your users knowing, and that's just one example. If a client can submit a jquery selector that is used by others, it's possible to escape it and inject more JS

Comment: That only affects that particular Client, not the integrity of the site that lives on the Server. Prepare your MySQL statements.

Comment: You could validate the strings.  I don't think there are any security issues as long as everything runs on the client side.  The person who injects XSS would only hurt themselves.

Comment: @SterlingArcher that example injects not just a string, it's outside of the quotes. In my case everything would be inside quotes with quotes stripped out.

Comment: @user2182349 in my case other people would be running the selector.

Comment: @Harry - then validation would work.  You can't inject anything with just letters, digits, dashes and underscores.

Comment: @user2182349 thank you, feel free to submit that as an answer.

Comment: Run a test like `if($(userString).length){ var itExists = $(userString); }` and you should be good.

Comment: Running on the client doesn't make it safe. All xss runs on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute

> When specified on HTML elements, the id attribute value must be unique
>   amongst all the IDs in the element's tree and must contain at least
>   one character. The value must not contain any ASCII whitespace.

Most of the time, ids are letters and digits, with hyphens or underscores.  This code requires that the first character of the id is a letter, followed by more letters, numbers, underscores and dashes.

If you are willing to limit the accessible element ids in that way, you may use the following validation scheme to prevent XSS.

**JavaScript** *(would run on the server)*

```
var i, l;
var submittedSelectors = ['<script>alert("ha");</script>','<img src="bogus.com?img=5">','geraniums','https://www.example.com','&lt;etc'];

l = submittedSelectors.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    validate(submittedSelectors[i]);
}

function validate(submitted) {
    if (!/^[a-z][\w-.]{1,62}$/i.test(submitted)) {
        console.log(submitted+' is not valid\n');
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log(submitted+' is okay\n');
        return true;
    }
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$submittedSelectors = ['<script>alert("ha");</script>','<img src="bogus.com?img=5">','geraniums','https://www.example.com','&lt;etc'];

foreach ($submittedSelectors as $ss) {
        validate($ss);
}

function validate($submitted = '') {
        $selector = filter_var($submitted,
                        FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
                        ['options' => ['regexp' => '/^[a-z][\w-.]{1,64}$/i' ]]);

        if (empty($selector)) {
                echo htmlentities($submitted).' is not valid'.PHP_EOL;
                return false;
        } else {
                echo $selector.' is okay'.PHP_EOL;
                return true;
        }
}
```

This limits entry to simple ids, and it is implied you would add the **#** into the selector.  If you are willing to allow more complex selectors, you can update the validation.